# Bonding strain gauges to ABS

Tags: gauge

As the question says, I've been looking for the best way to bond strain gauges to Acrylonitrile butadiene styrene (ABS). It will be a circular cross section ABS piece. I'm not sure if this is an electronics question per se, but the application is in this field. If not, I'd appreciate it if someone were to point out which forum to ask in.

[Further explanation: to be used for a torsion testing machine as the sensitive element which measures the torque applied on the specimen, which would be some sort of bone substitute. The torque is low, around 2 Nm, which is why I need a material which exibits more strain than aluminium or the like. ]

Comment: I think strain gauges can work, but if you have to measure torsion, how would you use the strain gauge? Wouldn't be simple the measure of angles?

Comment: @clabacchio The strain gauges will be in 45 degree arrangements on the shaft, taking the strain as the shaft twists due to the torque that the specimen tested is taking.

Comment: strain gauges are a real pain to mount; I remember doing that for about 2 weeks during the first few months I started work. I did it on aluminum and there was a special epoxy we used but I don't remember much. Check the Omega website; they should have tons of info on strain gages + other sensor.

Comment: I'll second Jason S' suggestion to check Omega Engineering http://www.omega.com .  You could also mirror your question in a specialized group dedicated to sensors: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/sensorforum

Answer (score 3):

Superglue has worked well for bonding strain gauges and accelerometers to plastic for me in the past.